# Android Studio emulators not able to connect to adb

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, google-chrome-os, chromebook

I have am Acer Spin 713 Chromebook with an 11th gen Intel I5.

When running on 10th or higher gen Intel CPUs, Android Studio on Chromebooks now supports emulators.

In Android Studio, I can bring up the AVD Manager, and start an emulator. The emulator loads and appears to be running correctly, but I get the following errors in the Android Studio error log:

```
3:53 PM * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037

3:53 PM * daemon started successfully

4:02 PM Adb connection Error:EOF

4:02 PM Failed to start monitoring emulator-5554

4:02 PM Adb connection Error:EOF

4:02 PM Cannot reach ADB server, attempting to reconnect.

4:02 PM Unable to open connection to ADB server: java.io.IOException: Can't find adb server on port 5037, IPv4 attempt: Connection refused, IPv6 attempt: Connection refused

4:02 PM Failed to start monitoring emulator-5554

4:02 PM Failed to start monitoring emulator-5554

4:02 PM Adb connection Error:EOF

4:02 PM Unable to open connection to ADB server: java.io.IOException: Can't find adb server on port 5037, IPv4 attempt: Connection refused, IPv6 attempt: Connection refused

4:02 PM Failed to start monitoring emulator-5554

4:02 PM Adb connection Error:EOF

4:02 PM Cannot reach ADB server, attempting to reconnect.

4:02 PM Unable to open connection to ADB server: java.io.IOException: Can't find adb server on port 5037, IPv4 attempt: Connection refused, IPv6 attempt: Connection refused

4:02 PM Failed to start monitoring emulator-5554

4:02 PM Adb connection Error:EOF

4:02 PM Unable to open connection to ADB server: java.io.IOException: Can't find adb server on port 5037, IPv4 attempt: Connection refused, IPv6 attempt: Connection refused

4:02 PM Failed to start monitoring emulator-5554

4:02 PM Adb connection Error:EOF

4:02 PM Cannot reach ADB server, attempting to reconnect.

4:02 PM Failed to start monitoring emulator-5554

4:02 PM Adb connection Error:EOF
```

I can launch the same emulator from a shell command line, assuming I have ~/Android/Sdk/emulator & ~Android/Sdk/tools in my PATH, in that order, using:

```
emulator -avd Pixel_3_API_30
```

The emulator connects to adb, and I can run/debug apps in it with Android Studio.

Any suggestions on how to fix, or debug this?